# Using predict() with MCMCglmm

Tags: r, predict, mcmc

I'm worried that this has been addressed somewhere before, but extensive searching hasn't revealed the answer I'm looking for. I'm running a random slopes model in MCMCglmm where I have an individual-by-covariate interaction in the random effects compartment. When using predict() to get estimates from this model, I run into an error, which I can't seem to deal with. The simpler example below (a random intercepts model) runs into the same error so I wonder what I'm doing wrong?

The example data consist of 20 individuals measured 20 times each for some covariate, with 10 individuals in each of two groups, plus a covariate and a response variable (y):

```
set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, 20),
                  group = rep(1:2, each = 50),
                  covariate = rnorm(100), 
                  y = rnorm(100))

dat
```

I then fit a simple random intercepts model with a categorical fixed effect, a continuous fixed effect and a random effect:

```
library(MCMCglmm)

fit <- MCMCglmm(y ~ group + covariate, random = ~id, rcov = ~ units, data = dat,
    family = "gaussian", pr = TRUE, pl = TRUE, saveX = TRUE,  saveZ = TRUE,
    nitt = 13000, thin = 10, burnin = 3000)

summary(fit)
```

I then make up a dummy data set to get predictions for the first individual in group 1 across a range of covariate values:

```
dummy <- data.frame(covariate = seq(-3, 3, 1),
                        group = rep(1, 7),
                        id = rep(1,7))
dummy$y <- 0

predict(fit, newdata = dummy)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in predict.MCMCglmm(fit, newdata = preds, marginal = NULL) : 
  model for newdata has fixed effects absent from the original model
```

And I don't really understand it, given all the fixed effects are included in both the model and the dummy data set and there are no missing values anywhere. If anyone could help I'd be very grateful!

Best wishes,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a constant group, if you try:

```
dummy <- data.frame(covariate = seq(-3, 3, 1),
                    group = c(rep(1, 3),rep(0,4)),
                    id = rep(1,7),y=0)
predict(fit, dummy)
```

this will work.

Comment: I believe the user wants the group to stay constant at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Only 18 months late but... I just tried running predict.MCMCglmm on model results with an intercept plus random effects, without creating a dummy dataset, and the resulting predictions ignored the random effects (they were identical for every data point). I think your problem is that 'id' is a random effect not a fixed effect. The error explicitly mentions absent fixed effects.